# Velocity gradient in polar coordinate

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, gradient-descent, continuum-theory

I just want to convert velocity gradient in polar coordinate to velocity gradient in Cartesian one (i.e. $\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}=f\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)$). How can I convert these terms into each other?

Indeed, I have a fully developed boundary condition in the outlet of my computational domain. In the attached image, this boundary condition should be employed in the $\Gamma_2$ region. As can be seen, The domain is defined through polar coordinates. So in order to use the fully developed B.C ($\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$), I should convert them in the equations based on $\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta}$ or something like this. Can anybody tell me more about its equations in polar coordinates? 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPpSh.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematics.SE]. Just to clarify you have a polar to cartesian transformation of velocities $$ \left(\begin{matrix}v_{x}\\
v_{u}
\end{matrix}\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{matrix}\right]\left(\begin{matrix}u_{r}\\
u_{\theta}
\end{matrix}\right) $$ and you want to take spatial derivative (gradient) of both sides of the equation?

Comment: Thank you. I want to convert the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ into a relationship based on derivatives of radial and angular velocities and also based on spatial parameters in polar coordinate.

Comment: Can you please give a little more details in the post on what you are trying to evaluate and what steps have you taken to get there. The question lacks details right now to be answered effectively IMHO. Best to describe your variables and coordinate frames you are working with.

Comment: OK. Imagine we have a relationship which is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$. I am working with polar coordinates so using this relationship is not acceptable. I wanna convert this term into derivatives of $u_r$ and $u_\theta$ based on $r$ and $\theta$. But I don't have any idea to transform this relationship into polar coordinates. If you want more information, I can mail you to clarify it meticulously.

Comment: I meant for you to [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3120038/edit) the question to add details. Also, you need to explain what the variables represent. Is this a fluid model, or something else?

Comment: I edited the post.